# Is there powershell command to select the line with particular string(time) and have to print count values Total calls Generated:156?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

- step-1 we have to go the location path -eg -C:\Jobs\logs.
- step-2 open the log file with current date in format-‘YYYY-MM-DD’(eg-2021-06-16.log).
- step-3 for completion time which will be input. In this scenario-5:02:21. I have to print the count values for the below sample log text.

  2021-06-16 03:30:00.7185  INFO Running GetCallGenForFullRun query
  2021-06-16 03:32:49.1254  INFO Query complete. Elapsed time: 168 seconds, Call Candidiate count: 713755
  2021-06-16 03:32:49.1254  INFO Generating Call Logs...
  2021-06-16 05:02:11.6588  INFO Deleting records from PRESCRIPTION_CallGen table
  2021-06-16 05:02:21.2377  INFO Call Gen Program Complete. Total elapsed time: 0 seconds, **Total Calls Generated: 156**

I need powershell command to select the line with time-5:02:21 and have to print Total calls Generated:156.

i tried the below code

```
cd C:\Jobs\logs
$TodayDate = $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
$Text = Select-String -Path "C:\Jobs\CallGenJob\logs\$TodayDate.log" -Pattern '2021-06-16 05:02:21'
echo $Text
```

Answer (score 0):

get-content -path C:\your\path.txt | findstr "$text"